# Unknown or uninitialised column: 'rc.f'. in R

Tags: r, warnings

I am getting this warning and no clue what it means.

I do not have a column rc.f in my data set.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What is the function call that gives you this error? What's your data like? please update your answer with this info at least. Use `dput(your_data)` if you can.

Comment: I am using data1 <- subset(data, select -c(var1, var2, etc))

Comment: `data1 <- subset(data, select(-c(var1, var2, etc)))` don't know if this was the problem, but you were missing one parenthesis, try this.

Comment: Still we need to see your data to give a better answer.